# Queing messages in local database and until network is available

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get my messages to be saved in local database so that i can upload to server at the time of network availability.What method shall I use..
Pls help me..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real question at first.
you have to implement sqlite in your application and register a broadcast receiver for Network change intents and upload it to server at right time.